# How to not redirect Twitterbot when using cloudflare SSL?

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, twitter, cloudflare

Twitter Cards (twitter:image or og:image) won’t allow https from a shared SSL including Cloudflare. The workaround mentioned is to create an .htaccess file and add code to **not** redirect twitterbot to the shared https. The problem is this is breaking my pages saying there are too many redirects.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !Twitterbot [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
</IfModule>
```

That being said, when I run the page through Twitter Card Validator when I have that .htaccess code, the image *does* show up fine on the Twitter Card Validator. But as I mentioned, the website breaks because of too many redirects.

I tried removing the .htaccess code and putting the twitter card image in a directory called /social/ and putting this page rule in Cloudflare: **example.com/social/ - Disable Security** as the first rule (only one rule works per page), and this simply is ignored by twitterbot even though if i manually put the path to the image in that directory it’s correctly not redirecting to https.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/social/image.jpg">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://example.com/social/image.jpg">
```

When validating the page on Twitter Card Validator and using ?utm_source=a-random-number to make sure it's pulling a fresh page, it pulls all the info correctly except for the image. Facebook pulls the image fine, it's just twitterbot's incompatibility with Cloudflare's flexible shared SSL. I'm not on WordPress and this is on Apache. There is currently no .htaccess file. Any ideas?

=============

*EDIT*

Ok, got it working. The solution of adding:
example.com/social/ - Disable Security
on Cloudflare's SSL page rules was correct, but I also had to include two meta og parameters on the head:

```
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1200" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="630" />
```

without that the image wouldn't show on Twitter Card Validator, but does when you add it. Hope that helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

The redirect loop isn't caused by the Twitterbot exception (that would simply prevent the rule being executed), but because you are checking the `SERVER_PORT`. When using "Cloudflare's flexible shared SSL" your *application* server is always communicating on port 80 (ie. HTTP). Cloudflare is an SSL proxy. The connection from the client to Cloudflare is secure, but the connection from Cloudflare to your application server is not. Reference: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170416#h_4e0d1a7c-eb71-4204-9e22-9d3ef9ef7fef

Instead of checking the `SERVER_PORT` in order to determine whether the client is not yet on an HTTPS connection, you should check the `X-Forwarded-Proto` HTTP request header instead (set by the Cloudflare proxy). Reference: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170986-How-does-Cloudflare-handle-HTTP-Request-headers-

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !twitterbot [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I've combined your two conditions that check the *hostname* (also avoids the need for the `OR` flag). Unless you are serving multiple domains/subdomains/hostnames from this account then that condition is not required at all.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing. (Test with 302 - temporary - redirects to avoid caching issues.)

Comment: Thanks @MrWhite, unfortunately it still gave the too many redirects error. Checked it on another PC as well. Not sure what's causing the issue. Thanks again though.

Comment: Hhhmm curious, do you have other directives in your `.htaccess` file? (Although I assume not from your question.) Examine the HTTP request headers your application receives and/or if you are using PHP, dump the contents of the `$_SERVER` superglobal - when accessing your site over HTTP _and_ HTTPS - that will contain all the information you need in order to determine the required HTTP to HTTPS redirect in `.htaccess`.

Comment: Also check the network traffic in the browser to determine the exact nature of the redirect. ie. from/to, from/to, etc. I assume it's redirecting to itself (ie. HTTPS) repeatedly. However, if you have redirect logic in the application itself then it could be HTTP to HTTPS to HTTP to HTTPS to HTTP.... etc.

Comment: Thanks again. I just spoke with my webhost's support. They looked everything over and said the loop is caused by cloudflare's flexible SSL. They told me I need to create a setting there and without the .htaccess code. I had already tried that but twitterbot was still not showing the og:image. Works fine in Facebook. Other then putting the images in a special directory with a cloudflare page rule not to redirect it to https not sure what else to do. Will keep trying and report back if I solve this. Thanks again.